# Norm of Riemannian curvature tensor on an Einstein manifold under the RIcci flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to prove that if $(M, g_0)$ is Einstein and $g(t) = (1-2\lambda t)g_0$ is a solution to its Ricci flow, then $\|\operatorname{Rm}(t)\|^2 = C R(t)^2$, where $R$ is the scalar curvature and $C$ is a constant depending only on $g_0$. This is a claim I've seen in a book but I'm not sure which norm they're using. Assuming it's the one induced by the metric, we have: $\|\operatorname{Rm}\|^2 = g^{ri}g^{sj}g^{pk}g^{q\ell}R_{rspq}R_{ijk\ell}$, but how can we relate this to the Ricci tensor? I'd appreciate any help. This is the discussion in the book: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "a constant depending only on $g$"? How about if I define the constant to be $C = \|\text{Rm}\|^2/R$, at least in the case $R\ne 0$?

Comment: A more reasonable question is whether this is true with a constant depending only on the dimension. But it's false in general -- there are Einstein metrics with zero scalar curvature but nonzero Riemann curvature (Calabi-Yau manifolds, for instance).

Comment: If you add the additional hypothesis that the dimension is 2 or 3 or the manifold is locally conformally flat (either of which implies that the Weyl curvature is identically zero), then this is true with $C = 2/(n(n-1))$, where $n$ is the dimension. See Proposition 7.28 in my _Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds_.

Comment: @JackLee you're right. I should've added more context. Thanks for the comments. Do you think it's ok now?

Comment: Piggy-back on Jack's comment: the orthogonal decomposition of the curvature tensor of an Einstein manifold is $${\rm Rm} = \frac{R}{n(n-1)} g \wedge g + W.$$Hence $$\|{\rm Rm}\|^2 = \frac{R^2}{n^2(n-1)^2} \|g\wedge g\|^2 + \|W\|^2.$$The norm $\|g \wedge g\|^2$ is easy to compute, but you don't have control over $W$ in general. Here, $\wedge$ stands for the Kulkarni-Nomizu product of twice covariant symmetric tensor fields.

Comment: Ah, this is an entirely different question. There's an easy answer, which I'll give in a moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Third Edit (the charm??):**
I don't know what Chow and Knopf had in mind when they wrote the equation $|\text{Rm}(t)| = CR$, because it's just wrong. But there's a very simple argument to show that the Ricci flow on a positive-scalar-curvature Einstein manifold has a Type I singularity.

Since the evolution of the meetric has the form $g(t) = a(t) g_0$ for some positive function $a(t)$, the inverse metric, $(0,4)$-Riemann curvature tensor, and scalar curvature transform as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Rm}(x,t) &= a(t)\,\text{Rm(x,0)},\\
R(x,t) &= a(t)^{-1} R(x,0),\\
g(x,t)^{-1} & = a(t)^{-1} g_0(x)^{-1}.
\end{align}
$$
(See Theorem 7.30 in my *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds*.)
Thus the squared norm of $\text{Rm}(x,t)$ satisfies
$$
\begin{align}
\|\text{Rm}(x,t)\|^2 &= g(x,t)^{-1}*g(x,t)^{-1}*g(x,t)^{-1}*g(x,t)^{-1} * \text{Rm}(x,t)*\text{Rm}(x,t) \\
&=a(t)^{-2}\|\text{Rm(x,0)}\|^2
\end{align}
$$
(where the asterisks represent contractions on various indices). Plugging in $a(t) = C(T-t)$ shows that $\|\text{Rm}(x,t)\|(T-t)$ is constant for each $x$. Since a complete Einstein manifold with positive scalar curvature must be compact by Myers's theorem, this quantity is bounded on $M$.

Here's why $|\text{Rm}(t)| = CR$ (or maybe they meant $CR(t)$) is not true no matter how you interpret it. If you interpret the left-hand side as a pointwise norm, it can't be correct because $R(t)$ is constant for each $t$ while $|\text{Rm}(t)|$ is not. If you interpret $|\text{Rm}(t)|$ to mean the global $L^2$ norm (i.e., the square root of the integral of the squared pointwise norm), then it's not true either because when $g(t) = a(t) g_0$ we have $R(t) = a(t)^{-1}R(0)$ while
$$
\left(\int_M |\text{Rm}(t)|^2dV_{g(t)}\right)^{1/2} = 
a(t)^{-1+n/4}\left(\int_M |\text{Rm(0)}|^2dV_{g_0}\right)^{1/2}.
$$
(See Theorem 7.30 in IRM.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You are right again that it should be $R(t)^2$, that was a typo. I'd been struggling with this for days now and didn't imagine it would come down to a trick like this, but it's correct so I'll take it.

Comment: In what sense is $C$ a constant?

Comment: @Deane: Sorry, I was too hasty. The norms involved have to be global norms. I'll edit.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade: See my edit above. I think we need more information to figure out what's really going on here.

Comment: @JackLee the book I'm looking at is "The Ricci Flow - an introduction", they make this claim at the beginning of chapter 8. From other instances where $\|\text{Rm} \|^2$ appeared, its definition (coordinate-wise) is exactly the one in my original post. They assume only that the manifold is Einstein and that the initial scalar curvature is positive. I'll put an image of the discussion in the book right now. If you see it and are able to comment back, I'll appreciate it, thanks for the corrections.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade: Hmm -- the formula you circled, $|\text{Rm}(t)| = CR$, is different from the one in your current post, which has $R(t)$ on the right-hand side. The only way this formula could be correct is if they're interpreting $|\cdot|$ to mean a global (integrated) norm, because $R$ is constant on the manifold but the pointwise norm of $\text{Rm}$ is generally not. I don't have the book at home with me -- would you check and make sure you're interpreting that expression correctly?

Comment: @JackLee Thanks. They're different because the book generally doesn't distinguish between $R(t)$ and $R$ and I thought I'd make it clearer in my post, I think the authors expect the reader to know from context. It makes things confusing, but I think I'm interpreting it correctly. The book has lots of issues like that though. I agree with you that it only makes sense if it's a global integrated norm if $R$ stands for $R(0)$, but nowhere in the book do they define such a norm (the only definition of norm they make explicit is the one in my current post). For this reason and also because (+)

Comment: there's a result in the book which implies that in this case $\|\text{Rm}(t) \| \to \infty $ (which wouldn't be true if it was constant), I think it's $R(t)$. On the other hand, your original interpretation could be the intended one by the authors but that'd be really weird for me.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade: The more I look at this, the less sense it makes. You're right that it wouldn't make any sense to interpret the right-hand side as $CR(0)$. But it doesn't make sense to interpret it as $CR(t)$ either, because the formula is incorrect whether you interpret the norm as a pointwise one or as a global one.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade: If all you need is a proof that $|\text{Rm}(t)|\to \infty$, there's an easy argument. I'll edit my answer to explain that.

Comment: @JackLee Thanks again. If you could edit your answer to show why the formula doesn't make sense whichever way we interpret it, I'd accept that too, although it'd make me sad to know the book is that wrong.

Comment: I agree with your second edit. However I'm quite confused now, since this is precisely the opposite of what the book claims (they later say this solution is a type $I$ singularity, whose definition I'll include now).

Comment: @JackLee Thanks! But do you agree with the claim in the book that this solution is then a type $1$ singularity? Because it appears what you've just proved is the opposite.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade: Oy. Well, there's a much easier argument to show that it's type I. The mistaken equation $|\text{Rm}(t)| = CR$ was just a red herring. I'll do another edit, and then hopefully we can be done with this.

Comment: @JackLee thanks again for all your patience! This is driving me nuts.

Comment: That settles it! Thanks a lot!